Trouble installing Matrix package
I've been having issues installing Matrix on R. I never had issues in the past. I ran into issues when my installed version of Seurat updated to v5, which changes the assay type to Assay5. I would have to change a lot of my code to figure out how to work with Assay5 at this point, so I decided to downgrade Seurat to version 4.0.2 which worked perfectly fine before. Someone I work with has that version of Seurat and version 1.3.4 of Matrix, so I decided to install that version to be compatible. I have R version 4.2.3.
I ran this line and received the following error:
remotes::install_version("Matrix", version = "1.3.4", repos = "https://cran.r-project.org")
ld: warning: -single_module is obsolete
ld: warning: -multiply_defined is obsolete
ld: warning: search path '/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0' not found
ld: warning: search path '/usr/local/gfortran/lib' not found
ld: library 'gfortran' not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Matrix.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Matrix’

removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/Matrix’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
installation of package ‘/var/folders/ry/rg1yzt75375_hp0p6qfqqvs00000gn/T//Rtmp9d3IQZ/remotes7f57428bd1cd/Matrix’ had non-zero exit status

I also tried this, resulting in the same error:
packageurl <- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Matrix/Matrix_1.3-4.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
I went to the CRAN repository and downloaded the matrix file onto my computer to try to upload it that way. I have permissions to read and write the file, but I still got the same errors as above.
install.packages("~/Downloads/Matrix_1.3-4.tar", repos = NULL, type = "source")
I would really appreciate any help as it shouldn't be this difficult to install a package that I've had downloaded in the past. Thank you!

"gfortran not found" and the paths that you give above imply that you are running on MacOS and should probably go to https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/, download the installer for  gfortran-6.1.pkg, and install it ...

I suspect you will be able to find duplicates if you search on the error text.
